# How do I make a wrapper the same width as the image within?

Tags: html, css

I have a wrapper around an image:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <img class="image" src="image.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Here is the `css`:

```
wrapper {
    backgroundImage: `url(image.jpg)`,
    backgroundSize: contain,
    display: block,
    padding: 0px,
    position: relative,
    height: auto,
    width: 100%
}

image {
    border: 0px,
    height: auto,
    left: 0px,
    opacity: 0,
    padding: 0px,
    position: absolute,
    top: 0px,
    width: 100%
}
```

Why does the `wrapper` not stretch to the same width as the `image` inside it?  How do I make this work and keep the `image` and `wrapper` responsive?

Comment: Parents won't extend to accommodate the width of their children, if that's what you're asking. If this wasn't a rule, layouts would break (which they did, as IE6 got this rule wrong... http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/expandingboxbug.html)

Answer (score 3):

First as mentioned by @certifiedmay use `;` instead of `,`

To make your `wrapper` expand its `width` with the `width` of the `image`

Change `display` to `inline-block`

```css
.wrapper {    
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0px;           
    border:1px solid black;
}

.image {   
    left: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
    padding: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <img class="image" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSX3P.png"/>
</div>
```

You can see wrapper border in red color and image border in black color

Answer (score 1):

you need to put semi colon at the end of your lines not a comma

also its

.wrapper {

```
background-image: url('image.jpg');
background-size: contain;
```

}

if you give your wrapper a width

.wrapper {

```
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
```

}
then give your image

img {

```
 max-width: 100%;
```

}

your image then should stay responsive inside your wrapper div